# Did Ubuntu mess up my EFI? Computer no longer boots from thumb drive

Tags: 15.10, bios, mint

I'm currently on a mac.  When I installed Ubuntu in the first place I created a bootable thumb drive, rebooted, held alt, chose the thumb drive, and that was about it.

I've decided I would like to give Mint a test run, so I did the same thing, but now this method doesn't work.  If I reboot and hold alt, my thumb drive shows up fine.  But if I choose it, Ubuntu starts.  And that's it.

To my knowledge, Ubuntu should have nothing at all to do with anything once I've gone through the trouble of choosing a different boot drive/disk/medium.  If anything goes wrong at all, I would hope for a black screen of death or something that looks like terminal.  Not the OS I specifically chose not to boot.

What on earth is going on here?

P.S.  [This post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164975/going-back-to-mac-os-x-after-installing-ubuntu) is why I'm pretty sure I should be able to continue using the method above.

I'm not sure if grub has anything to do with it, but I'm looking here now: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromUSB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Booting up into mac osx fixed the problem.

The only issue was installing it, which I found the solution to here:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164975/going-back-to-mac-os-x-after-installing-ubuntu

This did not fix the thumb drive issue in ubuntu at all, but it did get my computer back to a place where it could be usable.

Answer (score 1):

Try booting up into Mac OS and installing [rEFInd](http://rodsbooks.com/refind/), a custom bootloader for Mac that works much better with Linux/Mac OS dual boots than the stock bootloader.

Comment: I no longer have OSX

Comment: Oh. In that case, I would look at the following, and skip steps that aren't relevant to your install: http://www.rodsbooks.com/ubuntu-efi/

Comment: Thank you.  This is a pretty dense read which I'm not sure of the relation to my problem with, but it's a lot better than not being able to do anything.

Comment: If I have time later, I'll go through it and highlight specific parts I believe are applicable to your situation.